# How to download audio records from iPad/iPod/iPhone to computer/PC without iTunes?

Tags: ipad, audio, data-transfer, desktop, pc

I received **iPad** from a co-worker. I need to download **audio records** from dictaphone/recorder to my desktop/PC (**not** Mac).

---

I connected the iPad to my PC using **USB** cable. Through my PC I started browsing it. I cannot see audio files. I can see only **DCIM** folder and PNG and JPG pictures in it.

I tried to send them from iPad to my email. But these audio files as attachment are not sending. They are too big for sending via email.

I **don't** have **iTunes** on my PC. So I can't use it.

---

**Question:** how can I download audio records from the iPad?

Comment: Did you make a google search ? --- https://imusic.iskysoft.com/itunes/itunes-alternative.html --- https://www.google.fr/search?&q=download+musics+from+ipad+without+itunes

Comment: I tried  iSkysoft. That does not work. It looks for music only. I need audio records from Recorder. Floola also does not work. So that was just time wasting.

Comment: There are options to indirect access to your audio recordings for ex. via uploading them to one of the cloud (iCloud, Google Drive, Dropbox or OneDrive) providers and then downloading to your **not** Mac machine. If it is not a sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you talking about Windows when you say PC.

Windows itself can NOT access applications data folder, if you dont install any software on Windows you just can't access those files directly.

Maybe you can send them via e-mail, WhatsApp, (whatever, something via internet), but, it depends if your app has this feature. Built-in app recoder from iOS can do that.